# Adding new values to the bottom of dataframe + matching current values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a `main` `df1`:

| Name: | ID | ID2 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | 1 | 01 | 100 |
| Robert | 12 | 012 | 80 |
| William | 123 |  | 65 |
| Jul |  | 01234 | 87 |

and then I wanted to add `df2`:

| Name: | ID | ID2 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jul | 1234 | 01234 | 87 |
| William | 123 | 0123 | 80 |
| Steven | 12345 | 012345 | 99 |

So in the case where `df1` is my `main` dataframe I want to add the new values from `df2` to `df1`. In the case where the value for `name` in `df1` is new, I want it added to the bottom of `df1` and in the case where the value for `name` does exist in `df1` already I would want the current row to be overwritten with the new `df2` value(s) and stay in the same row that it was prior to the `df2` values being added.

So my final_df would look like this:

| Name: | ID | ID2 | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Michael | 1 | 01 | 100 |
| Robert | 12 | 012 | 80 |
| William | 123 | 0123 | 80 |
| Jul | 1234 | 01234 | 87 |
| Steven | 12345 | 012345 | 99 |

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to do a UNION between your two dfs. Try this:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Comment: Hey i've tried this and it works in the case for new data in the 'final_df ' - it will add the new data to the bottom. But in the case where we are adding data that already exists - for example adding 'Jul' and 'William' it still gets added to the bottom of the 'final_df ' and does not overwrite the already existing names from df1